# Drag and drop reorder list box was closed

Tags: windows-phone-8

In test.xaml

```
<rlb:ReorderListBox
        x:Name="reorderListBox"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Margin="12,0,12,12"
        IsReorderEnabled="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <rlb:ReorderListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                    Margin="12,4,12,4"
                    FontSize="36"
                    Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </rlb:ReorderListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </rlb:ReorderListBox>
```

int Test.xaml.cs

```
 public void loadSource()
    {
        try
        {
            var xElem = XElement.Load("Data/SourcePage.xml");

            var SourceNews =
                from elem in xElem.Descendants("SourceNews")
                select new ProNewsApp.Object.ObjectSource
                {
                    Name = elem.Attribute("PageName").Value
                };
            reorderListBox.DataContext = SourceNews.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I'm follow here http://reorderlistbox.codeplex.com/ and my problem is when i'm drag and drop and my app was closed ?Why it's closed when I drag item ?How do i fix it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ObservableCollection as the source of ReorderListBox. As the ReorderListbox changes indexes when items are reordered in the Model. So, try using:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<YourPublicClass> _observableList;
_observableList = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<YourPublicClass>(SourceNews.ToList());
reorderListBox.DataContext = _observableList;
```

And after rearranging items you can see that they are also changed in "_observableList".